# _axios.default.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a react app that uses react-app-rewired, which considers Axios as a string with .cjs format.

this is my config-override.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd())
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath)

const appIncludes = [
  resolveApp('src'),
  resolveApp('../components/src'),
]

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.resolve.plugins = config.resolve.plugins.filter(
    plugin => plugin.constructor.name !== 'ModuleScopePlugin'
  )
  config.module.rules[0].include = appIncludes
  config.module.rules[1].oneOf[1].include = appIncludes
  config.module.rules[1].oneOf[3].options.plugins = [
    require.resolve('babel-plugin-react-native-web'),
  ].concat(config.module.rules[1].oneOf[3].options.plugins)

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(js|mjs|cjs)$/,
    exclude: /(@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime|node_modules[/\\](?!react-native.))/,
    use: {
      loader: "babel-loader",
      options: {
        babelrc: false,
        configFile: false,
        presets: [
          "@babel/preset-react",
          "@babel/preset-flow",
          "@babel/preset-typescript",
          "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"
        ],
        plugins: [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
        ]
      }
    }
  })

  config.module.rules = config.module.rules.filter(Boolean)
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ __DEV__: env !== 'production' })
  )

  return config
}
```

and I already tried this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11889#issuecomment-1114928008 and https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12700#issuecomment-1293290243

how should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed import from `import axios from 'axios'` to `import axios from '../node_modules/axios'`

Answer (score 0):

first of all, make sure you have axios installed in your packages :

```
npm install axios
# or
yarn add axios
```

then your webpack config should look something like that for override:

```
 // Add the following alias to your Webpack config to handle Axios imports correctly.
  config.resolve.alias = {
    ...config.resolve.alias,
    axios: path.resolve('./node_modules/axios'),
  };
```

then restart your server and test it again!

Comment: thanks for your answer but it didn't work